# Spread object values into input boxes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a javascript quiz app. Atm I'm stuck with putting a possible answer into one of the four boxes. So just to make sure you're understanding what I'm trying to become: I fetch questions from an API. The answers are collected in an object and I want to take the answers and put them randomly in my 4 option boxes. I've tried some things but at this moment I have no clue what's going on... Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="questioncontainer" class="main-container">
        <div id="progression"><div id="progressfull"></div></div>
        <div id="header">
                <h2 id="vraagnummer">Vraag #</h2>
                <div><h2 id="timer"></h2></div>
        </div>
        <h2 id="vraaginput">In welke film wordt er kritiek geuit op de socio-economische situatie in Tsjechië in de late jaren 70?</h2>
        <div id="antwoordcontainer">
                <li id="Qst1"><p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p></li>
                <li id="Qst2"><p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p></li>
                <li id="Qst3"><p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p></li>
                <li id="Qst4"><p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p></li>
                <li id="Qst5"><p class="choice-text" data-number="5">Choice 5</p></li>
                <li id="Qst6"><p class="choice-text" data-number="6">Choice 6</p></li>
        </div>

        <button id="Quitgame">Ik stop ermee ze</button>    
    </div>

</body>
```

This is less code and has the most important stuff in it.

```
fetch(myUrl)
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((loadedQuestions) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < MAX_VRAGEN; i++) {
            vragen = loadedQuestions;
            vragenTeller++;
            mijnVraag.innerHTML = vragen[i].question;
            console.log(vragen[i]);
            choices.forEach((choice) => {
                choice.innerHTML = vragen[i].answers.object;
            });


        };
        startGame();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example. I decided it was better to create the options in HTML, rather than hard code seven answers and hide the ones that doesn't contain a selectable answer. This made the code slightly longer, but more dynamic.

The problem is that the answers came in form of an object, so I needed to use `Object.keys(question.answers)` so I had a max value to randomize. Then I just randomized a position, and cut that position out while adding answers in a while loop.

I hope the code is self-explanatory. I tried to refactor the code as much as I could.

Oh, and I just preload one question at the time, instead of fetching fifteen like in your original code.

```js
const quizURL = 'https://quizapi.io/api/v1/questions?apiKey=kAFKilHLeEcfLkGE2H0Ia9uTIp1rYHDTIYIHs9qf&limit=1';
var progression = 0;
var questionObj = {};
const questionEl = document.getElementById('vraaginput');
const answerContainerEl = document.getElementById('antwoordcontainer');
const currentQuestionEl = document.getElementById('vraagnummer');

document.getElementById('startGame').addEventListener('click', startGame);
document.getElementById('nextQuestion').addEventListener('click', nextQuestion);

function fetchQuestion() {
  fetch(quizURL)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((loadedQuestions) => {
      questionObj = loadedQuestions.pop();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

function startGame() {
  document.getElementById('startGame').setAttribute('hidden', true);
  document.getElementById('questionContainer').removeAttribute('hidden');
  nextQuestion();
}

function nextQuestion() {
  displayQuestion(questionObj);
  fetchQuestion();
}

function displayQuestion(question) {
  progression++;
  currentQuestionEl.innerHTML = `Vraag #${progression}`;
  questionEl.innerText = question.question;
  randomizeAnswerOptions(question.answers, question.correct_answers);
}

 // Here is the randomization for the options.
 // I created the radio buttons in javascript.

function randomizeAnswerOptions(options, answers) {
  const divContainer = document.createElement('div');
  var randomIndex, answerText = '', answerIndex = 0, isExistingAnswer = false, isCorrectAnswer = false;
  var optionsKeys = Object.keys(options);

  while(optionsKeys.length) {
    randomIndex = randomize(optionsKeys.length);
    randomIndex = optionsKeys.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
    answerText = options[randomIndex];
    isExistingAnswer = answerText != null;
   
    if (isExistingAnswer) {
      isCorrectAnswer = answers[randomIndex + '_correct']
      answerIndex++;
      divContainer.appendChild(createAnswerRow(answerText, isCorrectAnswer, 'answerInput' + answerIndex));
    }
  }

  answerContainerEl.innerHTML = '';
  answerContainerEl.appendChild(divContainer);
}

function createAnswerRow(answerText, isCorrectAnswer, inputId) {
  let answerRow = document.createElement('div');
  let bullet = document.createElement('input');
  let label = document.createElement('label');

  bullet.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
  bullet.setAttribute('name', 'answer');
  bullet.setAttribute('id', inputId);
  bullet.setAttribute('data-answer', isCorrectAnswer);

  label.setAttribute('for', inputId);
  label.innerText = answerText;
  
  answerRow.appendChild(bullet);
  answerRow.appendChild(label);
  
  return answerRow;
}

function randomize(max, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + (min || 0));
}

fetchQuestion();
```

```css
#antwoordcontainer > div > div {
  margin: 0.25rem;
}

label, input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
  background: pink;
}

input[type="radio"][data-answer="true"]:checked ~ label {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<button id="startGame">Start Game</button>

<div id="questionContainer" class="main-container" hidden>
  <div id="progression">
    <div id="progressfull"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="header">
    <h2 id="vraagnummer">Vraag #</h2>
    <div>
      <h2 id="timer"></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 id="vraaginput"></h2>
  
  <div id="antwoordcontainer"><!--ANSWERS--></div>

  <button id="nextQuestion">Next Question</button>
  <!--<button id="Quitgame">Ik stop ermee ze</button>-->
</div>
```